# Loop through objects and subtract different objects values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

As you might see the data structure looks like:

Dining Chair with the corresponding parts (productList state):

```js
0: {id: '0517f083-0e15-4876-8d1f-6fa45900431c', amountRequired: 4}
1: {id: '831b92b8-677b-42cc-a585-335ea4ccccb6', amountRequired: 1}
2: {id: 'addc65a8-c759-41d8-a18a-89fe446ad484', amountRequired: 8}
length: 3
id: "a269a247-0d38-4b47-9630-79c9ae545b68"
name: "Dining Chair"
```

Stock (articleList state)

```js
{id: '0517f083-0e15-4876-8d1f-6fa45900431c', name: 'Leg', amountInStock: 12}
{id: 'addc65a8-c759-41d8-a18a-89fe446ad484', name: 'Screw', amountInStock: 17}
{id: '831b92b8-677b-42cc-a585-335ea4ccccb6', name: 'Seat', amountInStock: 2}
{id: '6892b98b-9b87-4520-9a9e-7528f1d78cb4', name: 'Table Top', amountInStock: 1}
```

So you get the point, everytime a visitor order a product it should automatically checks if one of the parts is still in stock. So I was wondering how to subtract from stock.

```js
  const increment = (productId: string) => {

    const product = productList.find((item: ItemProps) => item.id === productId);
    product.articles.forEach((item: any) => {
      const test = articleList.find((stock: any) => stock.id === item.id);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Did you try subtracting the productList  `amountRequired` from the articleList`amountInStock`?

Comment: Indeed, but there are multiple parts....so looking for a reusable way to do that..

Answer (score 0):

I have added functions that you asked. It have more loops, better to change data strcture to decrease loops.

```js
parts=[ 
  {id: '0517f083-0e15-4876-8d1f-6fa45900431c', amountRequired: 4}, 
  {id: '831b92b8-677b-42cc-a585-335ea4ccccb6', amountRequired: 1}, 
  {id: 'addc65a8-c759-41d8-a18a-89fe446ad484', amountRequired: 8} ]
  
allStock=[ 
  {id: '0517f083-0e15-4876-8d1f-6fa45900431c', name: 'Leg', amountInStock: 12},
  {id: 'addc65a8-c759-41d8-a18a-89fe446ad484', name: 'Screw', amountInStock: 17},
  {id: '831b92b8-677b-42cc-a585-335ea4ccccb6', name: 'Seat', amountInStock: 2},
  {id: '6892b98b-9b87-4520-9a9e-7528f1d78cb4', name: 'Table Top', amountInStock: 1} ]

function getStock(id){
  return allStock.find(stock=>stock.id===id)
}

// this function return whether stock is enough or not
function isStockAvailable(num){
  for(let i=0; i<parts.length;i++){
    let part= parts[i]
    let stock =getStock(part.id)
    if (num * part.amountRequired > stock.amountInStock){
      console.log("Stock is not enough for " + num + " item")
      return false
    }
  }
  console.log("Stock is enough for " + num + " item")
  return true
}

isStockAvailable(1)
isStockAvailable(2)
isStockAvailable(3)

// this function deduct required items from stock and return new stock
function newStock(num){
  let newStock = allStock.map(stock=>{
    let part= parts.find(p=>p.id===stock.id)
    if(part){
      return {...stock, amountInStock:stock.amountInStock- num * part.amountRequired }
    }else{
      return stock
    }
  })
  
  return newStock
}

console.log("New stock after 2 item ordered: ")
console.log(newStock(2))
```

Comment: is there a way to temporarily store the quantity and when click on 'add to cart' it will then check the amount and do the calculation. If you now click on increment it will accumulate the value for instance 4, 8, 12......